# "Uncaught OAuthException: An unknown error has occurred." while attempting to make a wall post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, exception

I am using the following script to post a link to the wall of Facebook page:

```
ini_set("zend.ze1_compatibility_mode", "off");
require_once('facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php');
$appId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => $appId, 'secret' => $secret));
$access_token = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='.$appId.'&client_secret='.$secret.'&grant_type=client_credentials');
$access_token = preg_replace('/^access_token=/', '', $access_token);
$attachment = array(
    'access_token' => $access_token,
    'message' => 'message text',
    'link' => 'http://www.domain.com/',
    'name' => utf8_encode('link title'),
    'description' => utf8_encode('link description'),
    'picture' => 'http://www.domain.com/images/picture.jpg'
);
$facebook->api('/XXXXXXXXXXXX/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
```

It was working quite fine but since 2 weeks it started trowing the following error while absolutely no modifications were made:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught OAuthException: An unknown error has occurred.
thrown in /path/to/public_html/facebook-php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php on line 1033
```

By some primitive debugging I found out that if I comment out `link` element of `$attachment` array the problem went off. However it resulted that `name` at the Facebook page starts linking to picture file which is definitely not an option.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to execute this request through Graph API Explorer and got the same error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "An unknown error has occurred.", 
        "type": "OAuthException", 
        "code": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried running your query through the explorer as you might get a better error message. Make sure to change it to use your access_token and change to request method to post  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: hm, how do i run it through browser? do i just pass `POST` parameters as `GET` string?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer - input Graph API endpoint address, change method to POST from the dropdown, use “Add a field” to add name/value pairs for POST parameters … and then click send. (Although I doubt it will give a more helpful error message.)

Comment: You're right CBroe. Please see update.

Comment: Try putting the link you’re trying to post through the debugger, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug – does it complain about anything? How about when you try to post that link directly through the UI on facebook.com – any messages about the domain being blocked or something maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having the same issue, with a simple web based program that occasionally updates my client's facebook page with status updates about his inventory.

From what I can tell, for whatever reason this bug has been placed in a "Won't Fix" status and the feature in question has been deprecated?

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/397106947003500?browse=search_5013a59fc630a7b70100468

I don't know why JUST THE LINK FUNCTIONALITY would be deprecated, nor do I know what the new correct method is to post a link, since the Graph documentation still lists "link" as the correct field to use to do so.  Anyone?

On the bug page above, he gives a link that supposedly gives more info, but the link doesn't work.  I assumed that maybe the ".intern" portion wasn't supposed to be there, giving me this URL...

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/07/25/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/

...which DOES work, but I don't see any information on there that is relevant to the deprecated feature, or that otherwise helps me determine how to change my code to post a link.  Perhaps someone more knowledgeable about the Graph API can help!

[I really do wish Facebook would stop deprecating stuff; would it really have done any harm to allow this to continue to work?  They call it Operation Developer Love, but how can I love something that causes me extra work for no reason?]

Comment: Just posted a blog entry about this (http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/facebook-oauthexception-when). I can't figure out a way around it... you simply can't use the 'link' parameter in a facebook post anymore.